# PHP Advanced search error

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to setup a PHP advanced search to my website.
The code php is :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE";
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    if(count($_POST) > 0 && !empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $value = clean_data($value);
        $sql .= " $key LIKE '%{$value}%' OR ";
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql,' OR ');
    $res = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
}
```

html code is :

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <h3>
        Search for plate number
    </h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    <input type="text" name="car_model" placeholder="Enter car model">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

if i provide name and email as search terms i got this :

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [id] => 22
    [name] => fname lname
    [email] => whatever@hotmail.com
    [plate_num] => 775hgy
    [password] => 4194933072aab7975beb010542011ea1387d54b0
    [gender] => 
    [country] => 
    [gov] => 
    [cell_num] => 
    [username] => username
    [profile_pic_url] => 
    [car_model] => 
    [age] => 0
    [location] => 
    [job] => 
    [license_pic_url] => plate_images/497002597df3168ebd6e2813f29b53ea.jpg
    [android_key] => b0178e8f817cd6c9ec6b5a438633e634
    [creation_date] => 2017-08-19 22:46:33
    [modif_date] => 2017-08-19 22:46:33
    [is_online] => 0
    [num_friends] => 0
    [activation_code] => b23f8f7cea65f5c1d003165e8f1f5c61
    [account_stats] => 1
    [user_ip] => ::1
)
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'email LIKE '%what_i _entered_for_email%'' at line 1

I tried all provided solutions below with no luck.

I really do not know what is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: You should use parameterized queries. The `clean_data` function is probably not the safest. You also are making invalid SQL after the first iteration. This really should be 1 query with multiple where values.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with **OR** and missing single quote for **LIKE** Operator. Try anyone of the below code.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE";
    $i = 0; // loop count
    foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($key)) {
        $value = clean_data($value);
        $sql .= ($i++ > 0 ? " OR " : "")." $key LIKE '%{$value}%' ";
        echo "<br />".$sql; // print sql query and debug

        $res = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE";
    foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($key)) {
        $value = clean_data($value);
        $sql .= " $key LIKE '%{$value}%' OR ";
        echo "<br />".rtrim($sql,' OR '); // print sql query and debug

        $res = mysqli_query($connection,rtrim($sql,' OR ')) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first option is returning all rows in table because 1 is always equals to 1 and i do not need that.

Comment: Yup. 1st method will return all roes as per old answer. I have updated the answer with printing the sql query. Please show me the last printed sql query.

Answer (score 0):

update this

```
$sql .= " $key LIKE %".$value."% OR ";
```

Comment: This is also generating invalid SQL. The column should probably be backticked and the string probably needs quotes. It'd be better to post a parameterized answer.

Comment: @chris85 can you give an example please ?

Comment: @wfareed Of what, I made a comment on your question which should lead you to the right path. There are other answers here which should be pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE";
if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($key)) {
     $value = clean_data($value);
     $sql .= " $key LIKE '%{$value}%' OR";
    }
  }
    $sql = trim($sql,"OR");
    $res = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    }    

}
?>
```

**Explaination**

You should check count of **$_POST** before adding OR conditions then  run query after foreach loop and also add quotes for string example - `LIKE '%{$value}%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE";
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($key)) {
        $value = clean_data($value);
        $sql .= " $key LIKE '%".$value."%' OR";
    }
}
$sql = substr_replace( $sql, "", -2 );
$res = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
}
?>
```

Comment: `rtrim` would be better than `substr_replace`.

Comment: May be rtrim  is better but I didn't try ;)

Comment: Neither rtrim nor substr_replace has solve the error

Comment: really ! What is good about pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is wrong about that code ! anyways .. I write the script in a completely different way and it is functioning properly ! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hahaha!my pleasure to helps you